# Concept of 'serializing' complete memory of object

Tags: performance, serialization, programming-languages

I would like to ask a very general question about a technical concept of which I do not know whether it exists or whether it is feasible at all.

The idea is the following:

I have an object in Garbage Collected language (e.g. C# or Java). The objects may itself contain several objects but there is no reference to any other objects that are not sub-element of the objects (or the object itself). 
Theoretically it would be possible to get the memory used by this object which is most likely not a connected piece. Because I have some knowledge about the objects I can find all reference variables/properties and pointers that at the end point to another piece of the memory (probably indirectly, depending on the implementation of the programming language and virtual machine). I can take this pieces of memory combining them to a bigger piece of memory (correcting the references/pointers so that they are still intact). This piece of memory, basically bytes, could be written to a storage for example a database or a redis cache. On another machine I could theoretically load this object again an put it into the memory of the virtual machine (maybe again correct the references/pointers if they are absolute and not relative). Then I should have the same object on the other VM. The object can as complicated as I want, may also contain events or whatever and I would be able to get the state of the object transfered to anther VM (running on another computer). The only condition is that it would not contain references to something outside the objects. And of course I have to know the class type of the object on the other VM.

I ask this question because I want to share the state of an object and I think all this serialization work is just an overhead and it would be very simple if I could just freeze the memory and transport to another VM.

Is something like this possible, I'd say yes, though it might be complicated. maybe it is not possible with some VM's due to their architecture. Does something like this exist in any programming language? Maybe even in non garbage collected languages?

*NOTE: I am not sure what tags should be added to this question except from programming-language, also I am not sure if there might be a better place for such a question. So please forgive me.*

**EDIT**:

Maybe the concept can be compared to the [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) on Linux or hibernation in general.

Comment: "The objects may itself contain several objects but there is no reference to any other objects." That sounds like a contradiction to me. Could you clarify what you meant?

Comment: I mean no references to the outer world. No sub element of the object does reference anything else than sub-elements of the object, or the object itself.

Comment: But that can never happen, anything that is referenced from the object is a sub-element by definition.

Comment: Ok. Suppose A -> B stands for A referencing B. Then if we have A -> B and A -> C, then B and C are what I have called sub-elements of the object A. Then we may have D -> A with D not being a sub-element of A would be allowed, but C -> D would break the condition. Sorry if I cannot put it in the right words.

Comment: Why would that break the condition? Why isn't D considered indirect sub-element of A, using A → C → D? Or are you saying that cycles are not allowed?

Comment: Indeed D could be a sub-element and then the whole cluster starting with A would have to be serialized. But this cluster should not contain any references to anything outside the cluster, because they will make no sense when the object is inserted into another VM whereas the relations inside the cluster would make the same sense as they did before. (I just wanted to define D as an object not part of the cluster, but the example was bad). And cycles would be ok I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you will have to collect all references to other objects. including graphs of objects (cycles) without duplications. it would require some kind of 'stop the world' at least for the serializing thread. it's complicated to do effectively but possible - native serialization mechanisms in many languages (java) are doing it for the developer.
2. you will need some kind of VM to abstract from the byte order in different hardware architectures.
3. you will have to detach object from any kind of environment. you can't pass objects representing threads, files handles, sockets etc. how will you detect it?
4. in nowadays systems memory is virtual so it will be impossible to simply copy addresses from one machine to another - you will have to translate them
5. objects are not only data visible to developer, it's also structure, information of sandboxing, permissions, superclasses, what method/types were already loaded and which are still not loaded because of optimalizations and lazy loading, garbage collector metadata etc
6. version of your object/class. on one machine class A can be created from source ver 1 but on another machine there allready might be objects of class A built from source of version 2
7. take performacne into consideration. will it be faster then old-school serialization? what benefits will it have?
8. and probably many more things none of us thought about

so: i've never heard of such solution. it seems theoretically doable but for some reason no one have ever done that. everyone offers plain old programmatic serialization. maybe you discover new, better way but keep in mind you'll be going against the crowd